# How to fix binascii.Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found)

Tags: python, utf-8, hex, decode

I am trying to use codecs.decode to decode from hex to utf - 8. 
I get an error that there is a non-hexadecimal digit within my string, while I can't find anything like that and it's decoded successfully in sites like this one: https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-hexadecimal-to-utf8

I've tried using different methods like bytes.fromhex()but I get the same error.

```py
import codecs

hexString = "0x35303839372c312c333733002c003130003a3930"
utf = codecs.decode(hexString, "hex").decode('utf-8')
```

That's the expected outcome:
50897,1,373,10:90

The error I get:

binascii.Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the `0x` prefix:

```
import codecs
hexString = "0x35303839372c312c333733002c003130003a3930"[2:]
utf = codecs.decode(hexString, "hex").decode('utf-8')
```